# Duplicati Restore and zero byte files

Tags: duplicati

When we use Duplicati to restore a backup set, it always errs out on zero byte files.

We can restore these zero byte files individually, but not as part of backup set. That's to say that we can select zero byte files from the list, and those files will be restored, but, if we check the root folder, Duplicati errs out. We are seeing over 300 errors in the red modal box but cannot see any actual errors.

What it looks like to me is that Duplicati is throwing an exception, and exits, which would explain why we only see a couple folders and files restored from thousands.

Has anyone else experienced this behavior, and if so, were you able to work around this?

We are using Canary v2.0.4.18

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the log area, there should be more information about the error. If you see 300 errors, then clearly it does not just "quit", so something else must be happening. If you can get the real error message, maybe I can track it down.

I have not heard reports on this before, so maybe there is a simple explanation/fix/workaround.